# How do I use terminal emulator to talk to my iPad mini from my Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, ipados

I have Mac mini macOS Monterey; iPad mini 6 17.2 iPadOS and want to talk to the iPad mini from my Mac mini.

Comment: AFAIK there is no ssh-style remote login possible on iPadOS (and even if there would be, it would be limited to its own sandbox). What do you want to accomplish with such a login (there might be other ways to achieve it)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides some command line tools for iPadOS and iOS access from macOS as part of the Apple Configurator.

I would start there and then perhaps ask a follow on question explaining what you need to accomplish other than “talk”

- https://support.apple.com/en-is/guide/apple-configurator-mac/welcome/mac
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

The tool is documented mostly in the manual page once you install it, but this training page has a good synopsis of accessing the documentation.

- https://it-training.apple.com/tutorials/deployment/dm095#Scripting-with-cfgutil

It’s very powerful and can let you inspect the syslog of the iPad remotely, restore, revive, backup, restart and much more from the command line on your Mac.